# Monotone convergence theorem for sets?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, monotone-functions

Let $M = \bigcup\limits_{n=1}^\infty M_n$, $M_n$ be a measurable sets on $\mathbb R$ and $f$ be a measurable function on $\mathbb R$. Then I want to know how the equality
$$
\lim\limits_{N\to \infty}\int_{M\setminus \bigcup\limits_{n=1}^NM_n} |f(x)| \,dx = 0 
$$
holds. It seems something like monotone convergence theorem, but I know the monotone convergence theorem is for the monotone "functions". 
How can I justify this?

Comment: $\int|f|<\infty$ is required. See my comment answering LeGrandDODOM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The map $\nu:A\mapsto \int_A |f|$ is a measure.

Note that $A_N:=M\setminus \bigcup_{n=1}^NM_n$ is a decreasing sequence that converges to $\emptyset$.

Assuming $\int |f|<\infty$, we have $\lim_N\nu(A_N)=\nu(\emptyset)=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: use characteristic functions to write each integral as an integral on $M$.

Comment: Can you solve it without the assumption $\int |f|<\infty$ ? It seems to me the sequence of functions at hand is decreasing, so some domination is needed...

Comment: @LeGrandDODOM, without the assumption is obviously false. Take $f=1$, $M_n=[-n,n]$.